# Db4o, Java: Storing images using blobs

Tags: java, blob, db4o

I want to store images in Db4o using Blobs. How can I store them and how do I get them out again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this question answer: [How to stores and Pictures in Db40?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3124244/209899)

I repost my answer again, a bit updated with the links to the Java documentation:

There are [two basic ways](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/type_handling/blobs.htm) to handle Blobs. Either you store a blob as byte-array in the database or you use the special db4o-Blob-Type. Both have their advantages.

**Advantages/Disadvantages with byte array:**

- The blobs are in the db4o-database-file. So there's only a single file to copy around.
- Byte-arrays are part of the normal db4o-transaction and behave as expected.
- When storing large blobs, you might run into the [database-size limitation of db4o](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/tuning/performance_hints/increasing_the_maximum_database_file_size.htm). (256 GB)

**Advantages/Disadvantaged with db4o-blobs**

- The blobs are stored as regular files outside the database. This keeps the database itself small. Furthermore you just can access all stored blobs with a regular application.
- You always need to copy the blob-directory and the database.
- The db4o-blobs works outside the db4o transaction. This means that a db4o-blob behaves different than any other stored object (and the API is a little strange). However this allows to retrieve a db4o-blob without blocking the current transaction.

For your case I would store a byte[] array with the picture in the Person class. Or you create a special Image-class. This image-class contains then a byte-array with the picture. And a few methods to convert this byte-array from and to a Winforms-bitmap.